# TSLint no-inline-comments

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

Is there an equivalent of `no-inline-comments` for TSLint? Or an extension?

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inline-comments

Disallow:

```js
const myValue = 42; // The answer of everything.
```

Do:

```js
// The answer of everything.
const myValue = 42;
```

Comment: You might be able to use eslint https://eslint.org/blog/2019/01/future-typescript-eslint